# Is it possible to change the apk before pressing Go Live option in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, apk, signed-apk

I have enabled timed publishing option in google play console and updated a apk yesterday,Now Google play console is enabled with Go Live option for that apk.Here my problem is i want to change the apk with another updated apk and with the same timed publishing setting.Since i dont want to publish the new apk now.Please advice How can i change the apk without publishing the current apk?

Answer (score 1):

Got Solution!!!

Reupdated new apk to production by changing version code.After uploading new apk it shows success message for new update,old setting not changed.